# Visual Studio Team Services Monitor User

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

So far I was working my my project myself using Visual Studio Team Services using VS 2012, everything was good. Now I have added another user for my project and things are NOT working as I expected, below are my basic questions.

After my developer is done adding/editing files, does he needs to tell me the ChangeSet # to refer to? so I can get his Check-in's?

How Can I see What files he modified/Added? And is there a way I can get only the changes I want from the user instead of getting his/her entire changeset/files?

"Get Latest Version" does not really gets me the Latest Version of files which my developer modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below answers:

After my developer is done adding/editing files, does he needs to tell me the ChangeSet # to refer to? so I can get his Check-in's?
--> He doesn't need to give you Changeset# to get latest(his check-ins). You can go to Team Explorer --> Source Control Explorer and then right click on your project and select "View History" to look at all the changes done to the project. Do you see his changes in the history? If yes then "Get Latest Version" should work. Sometimes what happens if you try to get latest version in Visual Studio Solution and if the files changed are not part of solution you won't get those files. In those cases you need to get latest from Source Control Explorer.

How Can I see What files he modified/Added? And is there a way I can get only the changes I want from the user instead of getting his/her entire changeset/files?
--> If you double click on the changeset after following the above steps to go to View History you will see all the files changed. If you want to get only few files from a check-in you will have to get the latest at file/folder level instead of getting it at project level. i.e. Find out all the files changed using above method and then go to individual files/folders in the Source Control Explorer to get latest.

Comment: I viewed the History, and then Clicked on a Changeset, on the Right it shows all the files within the Changeset, I Right Clicked a file, but there is no option to Get that File, only options I see is "Compare" etc.

Comment: Once you find out which files you want using the above steps you will have to go to those files individually in source control explorer, then right click and select "advanced --> get specific version" or "get specific version" and then you can get that file by changeset #, date time etc.